# Appfabric Caching - Serialization

Tags: appfabric, appfabric-cache

I could not find an answer to this simple question. What kind of serializer is used in AppFabric Caching ?
Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's NetDataContractSerializer. 
found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg186017%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Strangely though if I cache a single array of 10^6 bytes then the app fabric cache reports one entry with a size of 1,008,640 bytes, i.e. much less expansion of the data than XML serialization would cause. Also I get the same size for both an array of zeroes and an array of random numbers, so no compression is at work here.

Comment: A byte array (byte[]) is the one case that's not serialized - byte arrays are passed thru as-is from the client to the cluster (and back). This is stated by Microsoft engineers here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3d159d3f-bc79-486d-95c3-0ea9ea7d6f71/appfabric-cache-serialization